# Changing Look and And Feel in JAVA not working when opening jar file

Tags: java, windows, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

So i am trying to change the look and feel of my java gui from nimbus to windows. Its works when i launch the program on netbeans but does not work when i build it and launch the jar file.
I am using windows 10

my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {

                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
       MainFrm f = new MainFrm();
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                f.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
```

Thank you!

EDIT:  my main project, where I had three forms. Where I changed only two to windows feel, I made all three to windows feel and it worked!. I guess this was the problem.

Comment: Does not output any error regarding this issue

Comment: Hey I just started a new project, and changed the look and feel from nimbus to windows, built and run, it was working.

Then I went to my main project, where I had three forms. Where I changed only two to windows feel, I made all three to windows feel and it worked!.

I guess this was the problem.

Comment: Please [answer the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with your solution to help others find it easier

Answer (score 2):

My Project had three JFrames, Where I changed only two JFrame to windows look and feel, after changing all three JFrames to windows look and feel, the problem was fixed.